# Secure AD Access

Tags: active-directory, php, security, windows-server-2012-r2

I was just trying to access and Active Directory-Server via php (ldap) to be able to use Windows credentials for a Website Login. I did this using xampp on my standard Windows connecting to a Windows Server 2012 R2 in a virtual Machine. Now moving to production I'm worrying about security:

The server running the php has to access the Windows/AD/LDAP-Server. However I read, that leaving the Logon-Server accessible from the outside would yield tons of brute-force attacks trying to get some password.

Still big companies, universities and schools let you log in with your work account from home. How do they do it without leaving a big security hole? Are there other options besides PHP/LDAP, do they whitelist the webserver's IP (how would I do that?) or do they run the Webserver and the AD on the same server (again, how would I do that)?

Comment: @MichaelHampton  That comment made me do a double take- its absolutely the developers job to worry about security and there is absolutely nothing an admin can do about poor code.  Security being built is is a #1 cybersecurity focus in the US and abroad https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/articles/knowledge/sdlc-process/secure-software-development-life-cycle-processes .

Comment: In case it's not clear, in my experience it's **both** the job of the sysadmin(s) **and** the developer(s) to **work together and communicate** about how to create a secure and user-friendly authentication system. As a sysadmin who has worked on AD-integrated authentication for in-house apps, I see it as my job to both challenge the developer(s) to use the authentication systems I'm willing to expose and also to give them as much information as I can on how they can leverage those sytems, as well as consider any requests they have for systems I might not have already deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Still big companies, universities and schools let you log in with your work account from home. How do they do it without leaving a big security hole?

There are several mechanisms that allow authentication to Active Directory from outside the LAN that are relatively secure. I've never seen a situation where the directory services ports, even read-only LDAP, are allowed through a firewall.

One fairly secure example of remote authentication to Active Directory is Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) protected by a Web Application Proxy (WAP).

Going from outside in:

- A firewall or security device or context exists between the Internet and the WAP server, such that only HTTPS (port 443) is allowed through to the WAP server.
- The WAP server receives requests at port 443 and proxies the ADFS service (see below). The external user interacts with the WAP and not the ADFS service directly. The WAP server is not a member of the domain and can only communicate with the ADFS service via HTTPS.
- Another firewall or security device or context exists between the WAP server (in a DMZ for example) and the ADFS server. Only port 443 (or an alternate port number) is allowed between the WAP server and the ADFS server.
- The ADFS server is "inside the firewall" and allows HTTPS connection only. The proxied user session communicates the user credentials to the ADFS server over SSL. The ADFS server is a member of the domain and can communicate directly with one or more domain controllers. It makes an authentication request using the provided credentials and then passes the result back to the original referring application.

Note that the ADFS server in question is not directly on the Internet, nor is it in the DMZ, so there are layers of protection. If the WAP server is compromised, the attacker is not yet right on the domain, and the only hole they have into the network from there is over port 443.

Nothing is 100% secure, but this example configuration is recommended by Microsoft (for what that's worth) for allowing "federated" application authentication to an Active Directory for users logging on from outside a protected LAN/WAN.

There are other relatively secure ways to pass credentials along to AD servers and pass the results back out, this is just one example using Microsoft products.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for the insight. So just to confirm, the chain is as follows: User->Webserver->WAP->ADFS->DC?

Comment: @ProgrammingMachine5000 No, it's just User -> WAP -> ADFS -> DC. With some firewalls/security groups/whatever filtering in between the user and the WAP and the WAP and the ADFS server.

Comment: also note that credentials in the form of token are not communicated from the the federation server to the app directly.  All of the token transport is client side.